# SQLAlchemy: ValueError

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have these tables:
1) User

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    fname = Column(String(45))
    lname = Column(String(45))
    mail = Column(String(45))
    password = Column(String(45))

    courses = relationship("Course", secondary=user_course, backref="users")
    universities = relationship("University", secondary=user_university, backref="users")

    def add_university(self, university):
        universities = self.universities
        universities.append(university)
        self.universities = universities

    def add_course(self, course):
        courses = self.courses
        courses.append(course)
        self.courses = courses
```

2) University

```
class University(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'universities'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(DateTime)
    name = Column(String(45))
```

3) Course

```
class Course(Event):
    __tablename__ = 'courses'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('events.id'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(45))
    year = Column(Integer)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'course',
    }

    events = relationship("Event", secondary=course_event, backref="courses")
```

So a many to many to many with user-course and user-university and a many to many with course-events (the parent of course).

When I try to add a university with my method defined in user it works but when i try to add a course i get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "/Users/arnoutaertgeerts/Documents/Eclips/SlideTalk 2.0/test_SQL.py", line 473, in <module>
    arnout.add_course(Analyse)
  File "/Users/arnoutaertgeerts/Documents/Eclips/SlideTalk 2.0/test_SQL.py", line 101, in add_course
    courses.append(course)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.9-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/collections.py", line 1046, in append
    item = __set(self, item, _sa_initiator)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.9-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/collections.py", line 1021, in __set
    item = getattr(executor, 'fire_append_event')(item, _sa_initiator)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.9-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/collections.py", line 714, in fire_append_event
    item, initiator)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.9-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 800, in fire_append_event
    value = fn(state, value, initiator or self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.9-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1026, in emit_backref_from_collection_append_event
    passive=PASSIVE_NO_FETCH)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.9-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 854, in append
    collection.append_with_event(value, initiator)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.9-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/collections.py", line 655, in append_with_event
    getattr(self._data(), '_sa_appender')(item, _sa_initiator=initiator)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.9-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/collections.py", line 1046, in append
    item = __set(self, item, _sa_initiator)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.9-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/collections.py", line 1021, in __set
    item = getattr(executor, 'fire_append_event')(item, _sa_initiator)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.9-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/collections.py", line 714, in fire_append_event
    item, initiator)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.9-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 800, in fire_append_event
    value = fn(state, value, initiator or self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.9-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1020, in emit_backref_from_collection_append_event
    _acceptable_key_err(state, initiator)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.9-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 982, in _acceptable_key_err
    manager_of_class(initiator.class_)[initiator.key]))
```

**ValueError: Object  not associated with attribute of type User.courses**

However, If I stop letting course inherit from Event, it does work!

Any ideas?

Comment: A side remark: you do not need to call `self.universities = universities` or `self.courses = courses` in order to add an object to the relationship - the first two lines in each method suffice.

Comment: please post code of your Event mapped class

Comment: Problem solved! http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/ticket/2674 Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! Here is the ticket: http://sqlalchemy.org/trac/ticket/2674